# Mute micro phone run time in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any API call which mutes the microphone in Action Script.If not please tell me how to mute the microphone in Action Script. I tried with the following ways

```
microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
microphone.setLoopBack(false); and
microphone.setSilenceLevel(100);
```

they don't make any difference to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a post which is saying,if we assign gain to 0 then microphone can be muted like below and its working.

```
microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
microphone.gain=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will not work very well. Once you set `gain` like that, if you would try to set `gain` again to some other value other then `0` it **will** set the `gain`, but **the sound will not be recorded anymore**. (at least to my experience)

To mute you can do it like this:

```
stream.attachAudio(null);
```

and to unmute:

```
stream.attachAudio(mic);
```